# C++ DoublyLinkedList unit test fails with smart initialization but succeeds with initialization via new

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am programming a `DoublyLinkedList` in C++ and one of the tests I wrote for this implementation is failing in a weird way.

I have created a `StubClass` for filling my `DoublyLinkedList`, which is defined as follows:

```
class StubClass {
public:
  int data;

  StubClass(int _data) {
    data = _data;
  }

  StubClass() {
    data = -1;
  }
};
```

I am using the Google Test framework for C++. I have the following fixture:

```
class DoublyLinkedListTest : public ::testing::Test {
public:
  DoublyLinkedList<StubClass> doublyLinkedList;
};
```

With the following test:

```
TEST_F(DoublyLinkedListTest, LargePushAndPopRoutineWithSmartInitializedData) {
  int repetitions = 12;
  for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++) {
    StubClass stub(i);
    doublyLinkedList.push_back(&stub);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++) {
    ASSERT_EQ(i, doublyLinkedList.pop_front()->data);
  }
}
```

The problem is that all the `StubClass` objects in the `DoublyLinkedList` object have their data field set to 11. Therefore the test fails, as the first item popped from the front should have its data field set to 0. The output of the test run:

```
Value of: doublyLinkedList.pop_front()->data
  Actual: 11
Expected: i
Which is: 0
```

Oddly, the following test does pass:

```
TEST_F(DoublyLinkedListTest, LargePushAndPopRoutine) {
  int repetitions = 12;
  for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++) {
    doublyLinkedList.push_back(new StubClass(i));
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++) {
    ASSERT_EQ(i, doublyLinkedList.pop_front()->data);
  }
}
```

This test uses the `new` keyword to instantiate the `StubClass` instead of the smart initialization in the failing test.

I do not have much experience with C++ and am only just learning about things like copy and move constructors. I suspect that I have probably made a stupid C++ beginner mistake in the failing test.

For completeness I will put my implementation of the `DoublyLinkedList` class below:

`DoublyLinkedList.h`

```
#ifndef PROJECT_DOUBLYLINKEDLIST_H
#define PROJECT_DOUBLYLINKEDLIST_H

#include "DoublyLinkedNode.h"

template<class T>
class DoublyLinkedList {
private:
  DoublyLinkedNode<T> *head = nullptr;
  DoublyLinkedNode<T> *tail = nullptr;

public:
  bool hasOneItem() {
    return head == tail && !isEmpty();
  }

  void push_front(T* data) {
    DoublyLinkedNode <T> *newNode = new DoublyLinkedNode<T>();
    newNode->data = data;

    if (isEmpty()) {
      head = newNode;
      tail = newNode;
    }
    else {
      newNode->setNext(head);
      head = newNode;
    }
  }

  void push_back(T* data) {
    DoublyLinkedNode <T> *newNode = new DoublyLinkedNode<T>();
    newNode->data = data;

    if (isEmpty()) {
      head = newNode;
      tail = newNode;
    }
    else {
      newNode->setPrev(tail);
      tail = newNode;
    }
  }

  T* pop_front() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
      return nullptr;
    }

    DoublyLinkedNode<T> *oldHead = head;
    if (hasOneItem()) {
      head = nullptr;
      tail = nullptr;

      return oldHead->data;
    }

    head->next->prev = nullptr;
    head = head->next;

    return oldHead->data;
  }

  T* pop_back() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
      return nullptr;
    }

    DoublyLinkedNode<T> *oldTail = tail;
    if (hasOneItem()) {
      head = nullptr;
      tail = nullptr;

      return oldTail->data;
    }

    tail->prev->next = nullptr;
    tail = tail->prev;

    return oldTail->data;
  }

  bool isEmpty() {
    return !head && !tail;
  }
};

#endif //PROJECT_DOUBLYLINKEDLIST_H
```

`DoublyLinkedNode.h`

```
#ifndef PROJECT_DOUBLYLINKEDNODE_H
#define PROJECT_DOUBLYLINKEDNODE_H

template<class T>
class DoublyLinkedNode {
public:
  DoublyLinkedNode *prev = nullptr;
  DoublyLinkedNode *next = nullptr;
  T *data = nullptr;

  /**
   * Will also set 'prev' on the nextNode
   */
  void setNext(DoublyLinkedNode *nextNode) {
    next = nextNode;

    if (nextNode) {
      nextNode->prev = this;
    }
  }

  void setPrev(DoublyLinkedNode *prevNode) {
    prevNode->setNext(this);
  }
};

#endif //PROJECT_DOUBLYLINKEDNODE_H
```

Comment: You're pushing the address of an item that's on the stack. Most likely this address will be the same every time, that's why all your items end up with the same value - they are all pointing to the same, undefined behavior inducing, garbage pointer.

Comment: What is *"smart initialization"*?

Comment: @user2079303 I thought that was the name for initializing an object without calling `new`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you are creating objects that are local to the for loop and then using addresses of these objects to push them into the list. Each of these objects is destroyed after the corresponding loop iteration terminates. In your case, they are all created at the same address on the stack, that is why it seems that they are all initialized with a data field set to 11. In fact, your list contains pointers to the same memory location used to create these objects, and the last thing that was written to this location is an object with a data field set to 11.

However, when you use `new`, these object are allocated on the heap on different locations. That is why everything works as you expect. In this case, you have a memory leak because your container does not delete these objects.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In my application I am using this `DoublyLinkedList` to store `String` objects from a framework that I use. These strings are often initialized like `String data = "Some data";` or `String data("Some data");`. Does this mean that those will also be destroyed after the function scope that creates them terminates?

Comment: @ThijsRiezebeek Yes, those are created on the stack, and are destroyed automatically when the enclosing scope terminates. One way to avoid problems is to allocate those `string` objects using `new`. Another (better) way would be to change your list class in such a way that it "takes ownership" of the objects it contains. List should make a copy of each object pushed into it. This way you do not need to worry if the object being pushed is allocated on stack or on the heap. You simply delete remaining elements in list destructor. This is how containers in C++ are actually implemented.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Your preferred way is probably what I will implement. One final question: how do I make a copy of an arbitrary class `T`?

Comment: @ThijsRiezebeek If you have an object `T t1;`, then statements `T t2(t1);` and `T t2 = t1;` create an object `t2` which is a copy of `t1`. For this to work, the type must be copy-constructible (most types are). I suggest some reading about copy constructors if you are not familiar with the topic.